# Editor opens wrong file when trying to commit

Tags: git

I am new to Git and am trying to commit changes to a repository. I have set up Sublime as my default editor with the following line in my .gitconfig file:

```
editor = C:/Program\\ Files/Sublime\\ Text\\ 2/sublime_text.exe -n -w
```

When I use `git commit` Sublime opens correctly, however rather than opening the COMMIT_EDITMSG file as expected, it opens a new empty file called $@ in the working directory. Writing a commit message and saving and closing the file results in the error message:

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message
```

I am using Git 1.9.5 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Put the unescaped path to the editor in quotes.

Comment: Can you have a look at this GitHub article to make sure you have configured Sublime to work with Git properly? https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/

Comment: Thanks James- removing the escapes and putting the path in quotes fixed the problem.

Comment: @JamesTaylor do you want to add an answer?

Comment: Yes, I will. I'm glad it fixed your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because the path of the editor is not configured correctly. Simply put the unescaped path in quotes.

It should look something like this:

```
editor = "C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe" -n -w
```

Hope this helps you!